# Vim: case-insensitive ex-mode autocompletion

Tags: vim, autocomplete, case-insensitive

I have the following line in my `~/.inputrc`:

```
set completion-ignore-case on
```

So that, in the shell, autocompletion happens case-insensitively. Is there something like this for Vim's Ex mode? I want to be able to type `:bundlei<Tab>` and get it autocompleted to `:BundleInstall`. Likewise, I want to type `:e ~/doc<Tab>` and get `:e ~/Documents/`.

Comment: `:help completeopt` has text indicating that `ignorecase` might be used for `longest` mode matches onl from buffer text. This doesn't look promising.

Answer (score 7):

try this new feature: `:set wildignorecase`

Answer (score 2):

This is not real answer. But if you install ambicmd, you will get good behavior to manipulate command lines.

https://github.com/thinca/vim-ambicmd

And add following into your vimrc

```
if globpath(&rtp, 'autoload/ambicmd.vim') != ''
  cnoremap <expr> <Space> ambicmd#expand("\<Space>")
  cnoremap <expr> <CR>    ambicmd#expand("\<CR>")
endif
```

You'll get `BundleInstall` with `:bi<space>` maybe.

Answer (score 1):

Add these to your .vimrc:

```
set ignorecase
set smartcase
```

With these, your examples work as described.  I couldn't find the explicit documentation that says those options affect command-line completion, but they appear to affect all patterns.